# Как обрезать вывод ссылки до имени файла?

Tags: javascript, php

в моей CMS есть модуль вывода товаров на любую страницу.

Выполняется загрузка товаров плиткой в нужную область страницы, заголовок товара представляет из себя ссылку на карточку товара.

Как обрезать данную ссылку до имени файла?
 То есть, чтобы вместо `site.ru/products/phones/phone1.html` было `/phone1.html`, а все остальное не выводилось?

Вся загвоздка еще в том, что ссылку я перенаправил в input, редактировав модуль, в значение `value=""`

Все выглядит вот так: `<input class="form-check-input" value="/241-honor/huawei-honor-view-20-60.html" type="checkbox">`
Интересует возможно ли это через PHP или JS, не редактируя сам модуль (пробовал, ссылка становится не SEF)

Возможно, что-то можно сделать с этим?
`$("#file a").each(function() {
  var parts = $(this).attr("href").split("/");
  $(this).text(parts[parts.length - 1]);
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри документацию на php.net по след. функциям parse_url и basename

```
$url = 'https://test.ru/file1.html';
$path = parse_url($url)['path'];
$filename = basename($path);
$withoutHtml = basename($path, '.html');
echo $filename; // file1.html
echo $withoutHtml; // file1
```

UPD

```
function transformURL($oldUrl) {
  $newUrl = basename($oldUrl);
  return '/'. $newUrl;
}
```

Пример:

```
$oldUrl = 'site.ru/products/phones/phone1.html';
echo '<input value="'. transformURL($oldUrl) .'" />';
// Вывод <input value="/phone1.html" />
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, подскажите, если у меня в php-коде модуля ссылка выводится вот так https://codepen.io/MorrisJerrald/pen/eYYGjyE, как применить Ваш код к ней? (url в value="" у input)

Comment: В ответе, дополнил код

Comment: Посоветовали вот что $mass=array('site.ru/products/phones/phone1.html','site.ru/products/phones/phone1.html') foreach($mass as $key =>$value){ $arr=explode('/', $value); print_r($arr[3].'<br>');}

Comment: Ссылки хранятся в массиве или базе данных? как сейчас работает текущий код?

Answer (score 1):

```
$data='site.ru/products/phones/phone1.html';

$arr=explode('/', $data);
print_r($arr[3]);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а если у меня таких товаров где-то 1000, как это все автоматизировать?

Comment: $mass=array('site.ru/products/phones/phone1.html','site.ru/products/phones/phone1.html') foreach($mass as $key =>$value){ $arr=explode('/', $value);
print_r($arr[3].'<br>');}